# How to breakdown text with a non-uniform delimiter?

Tags: vba, excel, split

I have this data in Excel:

[image]

But one of my clients needs it summarize per item in detail.
So above data needs to be converted to:

[image]

This way, client can analyze it per tracking and per item.
The text format is not really uniform since it is entered manually.
Some users use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to separate items. Some uses space and some doesn't bother separating at all. What's consistent though is that they put hyphen(-) after the item then the count (although not always followed by the number, there can be spaces in between). Also if the count of that item is one(1), they don't bother putting it at all (as seen on the tracking IDU3004 for *Apple Juice*).

The only function I tried is the **Split** function which brings me closer to what I want.
But I am still having a hard time separating the individual array elements into what I expect.
So for example, **IDU3001** in above after using **Split** (with "-" as delimiter) will be:

```
arr(0) = "Apple"
arr(1) = "20 Grape"
arr(2) = "5" & Chr(10) & "Pear" ~~> Just to show Alt+Enter
arr(3) = "3Banana"
arr(4) = "2"
```

Of course I can come up with a function to deal with each of the elements to extract numbers and items.
Actually I was thinking of using just that function and skip the **Split** altogether.
I was just curious that maybe there is another way out there since I am not well versed in *Text* manipulation.
 I would appreciate any idea that would point me to a possible better solution.

Comment: In general this looks a good candidate for a Regex.  But I see one problem: mixing multi-word names and no number (for count of 1). Eg is `Apple Pie - 2` one `Apple` and two `Pie`s, or two `Apple Pie`s?

Comment: @chrisneilsen Yeah that too. Although that item usually is the last entered item but still that will break the rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using a *Regular Expression* approach

Here's a demo based on your sample data.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim re As RegExp
    Dim rMC As MatchCollection
    Dim rM As Match
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim Detail As String

    ' replace with the usual logic to get the range of interest
    Set rng = [A2:C2]

    Set re = New RegExp

    re.Global = True
    re.IgnoreCase = True
    re.Pattern = "([a-z ]+[a-z])\s*\-\s*(\d+)\s*"
    For Each rw In rng.Rows
        ' remove line breaks and leading/trailing spaces
        Detail = Trim$(Replace(rw.Cells(1, 3).Value, Chr(10), vbNullString))

        If Not Detail Like "*#" Then
            ' Last item has no - #, so add -1
            Detail = Detail & "-1"
        End If

        ' Break up string
        If re.Test(Detail) Then
            Set rMC = re.Execute(Detail)
            For Each rM In rMC
                ' output Items and Qty's to Immediate window
                Debug.Print rM.SubMatches(0), rM.SubMatches(1)
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Based on your comment I haved assumed that only the *last* item in a cell may be missing a `-#`

Sample input

```
Apple Juice- 20 Grape -5
pear- 3Banana-2Orange
```

Produces this output

```
Apple Juice   20
Grape         5
pear          3
Banana        2
Orange        1
```